# Spring Boot Web java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IS_SECURITY_ENABLED Jetty

Tags: maven, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am getting this error

> 2017-04-20 22:58:08.573 ERROR 11463 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IS_SECURITY_ENABLED
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext.(JspRuntimeContext.java:197) ~[jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar!/:na]
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:150) ~[jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar!/:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:640) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:419) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:892) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext$JettyEmbeddedServletHandler.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:46) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:36) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.handleDeferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:186) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:121) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at com.analytics.bi.App.main(App.java:91) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-internal/Native Method) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:531) ~[na:na]
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [bi.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [bi.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [bi.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [bi.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

My Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>project-lyoko</groupId>
<artifactId>bi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>bi</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!-- The main class to start by executing java -jar -->
    <start-class>com.analytics.bi.App</start-class>
</properties>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.22</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
        <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.1001</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jgroups</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgroups</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>redshift</id>
        <url>http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <!-- <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources> -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <addResources>false</addResources>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
        <!--<plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>2.3</version> <executions> <execution> <phase>package</phase> <goals> 
            <goal>shade</goal> </goals> <configuration> <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar> 
            <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom> </configuration> 
            </execution> </executions> </plugin> -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am using spring-boot-embedded-jetty.
I can run the App on my local but when i mvn package and i run this on a remote instance (ec2) it will give me that error.

I have read many comments about jar issues and couldn't understand what this meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong jsp implementation classes.

`jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar` is invalid for Jetty 9.3.x

Use this instead ...

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.14.v20161028</version> <!-- same version as jetty itself -->
</dependency>
```

And figure out where you are getting that `jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar` from (likely a transient dependency) and exclude it.

Note: The `6.1.14` in that jsp jar hints at you having Jetty 6.1.14 also in your dependencies, that has to be removed, but it 100% not backward compatible with Jetty 9.x.  That might prove to be a difficult thing to remove if you still require Jetty 6.x for some reason.

Jetty 6.x is pre-Eclipse.  Jetty moved to the Eclipse Foundation starting with Jetty 7.x, and that change was very dramatic to the codebase.

Comment: i will try this tomorrow and i will let you know the result